# CS0433: The type some user control exists in both A.DLL and B.DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am facing one wired issue today, in my application there is on user control in Control folder when i try  to run the code i am getting error as **CS0433: The type some user control exists in both A.DLL and B.DLL**. i thought this may be because of the old compiled data in **"'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\"** so delete all the files in this folder. But it did not work and i am getting same error.

Same code was working before and now its giving problem.
Can any one tell me the reason of this error and how i can resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: From [Compiler Error CS0433](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/64wh5743.aspx): Two different assemblies referenced in your application contain the same namespace and type, which produces ambiguity. To resolve this error, use the alias feature of the [/reference (C# Compiler Options)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yabyz3h4.aspx) compiler option or do not reference one of your assemblies.

Comment: @Soner: i tried using alias but did not worked